# AIC: can MAP estimate be used instead of ML estimate?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, aic

Is it reasonable to use an information criterion such as AIC in which the maximized likelihood function is replaced by the maximized posterior function?

I know there are other criteria designed specifically for a bayesian setting, but I'm still curious about this adaptation of AIC.

Comment: BIC is often used and is similar to AIC.

Comment: @MichaelChernick so what? BIC does not solve anything about in here, it's just another criterion following similar logic.

Comment: A comment is not used to supply an answer. I just want the OP to be aware of other options.

Comment: AIC should only be used with MLEs. However, penalized MLEs can be used if the correct degrees of freedom are worked out. The logic is that the penalized MLE is the MLE for an equivalent unpenalized model with the correct degrees of freedom. Similar logic could apply with the MAP, because the prior serves the same function as the likelihood penalty. The challenge is determine the correct DF. Simon Wood has done some work on this, as related to his R package mgcv for generalized additive models. But, short answer: no, don't just blindly apply AIC for a MAP estimate with nominal DF.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, what Tim is saying is that your comment is completely irrelevant to the question.The OP asked whether or not you can use MAP estimates in place of MLEs in the AIC calculation...Your response was to mention that BIC is kind of like AIC and justified it by saying you "wanted the OP to be aware of other options" ... Options he already explicitly said he was aware of... I have to agree with Tim here.

Comment: BIC was never mentioned in the  question.

Comment: Dr @MichaelChernick, I see you dodged the real issue ("your comment in completely irrelevant to the question") to point out a fact that is as irrelevant as your original comment... The OP explicitly said they were aware of other options and that the question wasn't about that...