# Is there an AIC and BIC equivalent for MAP?

Tags: model-selection, aic, model-comparison, bic

I would like to know if there is an AIC or BIC equivalent for maximum a posterior estimation. I'm trying to compare several different models that have been fit using MAP, but I am unsure of the best way to compare these models. Can I use the likliehood in a way analogous to MLE, or is there a different criterion that can be used for model comparison?

Comment: Hi: AIC or BIC are used for model selection and the inputs are only the model's likelihood ( from the specific model's fit, it can be calculated ) and a penalty based on the number of parameters in the model. So, if you can calculate-obtain the  posterior likelihood when you used the "maximum posterior estimation method", then you can still use AIC or BIC AFAIK. Be careful with using non-nested models or models with different number of observations. There are "gotchas" when using it but I can't recall them.  There's a model selection book  (I think author is Birnbaum ? ). that covers them. .

Comment: I don't have the book but I've heard it was good ?  https://www.amazon.com/Model-Selection-Multimodel-Inference-Information-Theoretic/dp/B01JXS8IAS/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=model+selection&qid=1572724585&sr=8-7#customerReviews

Comment: This question seems quite odd to me, why would you do that? I think you should specify what is your model, so we can understand better what you have made your mind for. Also, you may be interested in the comments to this question, which is practically the same as yours: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272812/aic-can-map-estimate-be-used-instead-of-ml-estimate